# Error while editing existing GSI on my scheme

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, graphql, aws-appsync

I am using AppSync with DynamoDB and GraphQL API. My current scheme works as expected but when trying to edit existing GSI I am getting an error.

My current scheme looks like this:

```
type Item @model
  @key(fields: ["id", "version"])
  @key(name: "type-subtype", fields: ["type", "subtype"])
{
  id: ID!
  version: String!
  type: String!
  subtype: String!
}
```

I want to change GSI defined here to be:

```
@key(name: "version-type-subtype", fields: ["version", "type", "subtype"]
```

The error I am getting is `Schema Creation Status is FAILED with details: Failed to parse schema document - ensure it's a valid SDL-formatted document`.

Can someone help? Is there any constraint using sort key from primary index as hash in GSI that I am not aware of?

Thanks

Comment: It might be just a typo in your post but you are missing quotation mark after the `subtype`

Comment: @Tommy, yeah, that is a typo in post

Comment: Should it use `fileds` or `fields`? Seems to me another typo

Comment: First verify the typos - missing the parentheses after `"subtype"]`, the spelling of `fileds` are not present when creating the schema. Otherwise my recommendation would be to open up an issue in the amplify cli github repo - though it seems you might have already done that here: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/1720

Comment: Sorry about the typos, it is just here, not present when creating a schema. Yeah, I did open an issue on GitHub.